# Place views like symbols

Tags: android, view

After many searches and read so many posts I couldn't understand how can I deal with multiple views in a relative layout...
I have a base view (RelativeLayout) where I draw some lines and arcs and then I need to place some symbols (group of draws) and be able to select them.
I was thinking on create views like symbols and be able to place them anywhere and, when zooming or panning it changes everything at the same time.
I'm trying to create a 2D editor!

I already have the base view implemented with the gestures and everything works fine, but my problem it's with the views. I create the view, add it and place it with params:

```
 params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
 params.leftMargin = 30;
 params.topMargin = 30;                 
 this.addView(symbolView1, params);
```

It's really shows the view, but when I zoom/pan it disapears. If I try to move the view in the onDraw method of the base view it acts strange, it stretches my view...

My question are:

Am I structuring it right? THere is a better way to achieve this?
Where/How to change views position? It's in onDraw? Do I mantain the base view as RelativeLayout?